# How to add custom control before old custom controls in google map?

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-maps-api-3

I have 3 custom controls on 'TOP_CENTER' of google map. At first i want to show only 2("b1" and "searchButton"). When click on "searchButton", I want to remove "b1" and add "searchBox" instead like this

```
let b1 = document.createElement('div');
let searchBox = document.createElement('div');
let searchButton = document.createElement('div');
...
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(b1);
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(searchButton);
searchButton.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].removeAt(0);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].insertAt(0,searchBox);
});
```

"searchBox" should add to the left of "searchButton"(which i want) but it add to the right of "searchButton". How can i fix this?

Comment: Did you try removing all controls and then adding them in the order you want? (Maybe with a `setTimeout` in between). Did you try `map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].splice(0, 1, searchBox);`?

Comment: Thanks, i try this and it work 
          map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].clear(); 
          map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(searchbox);
          map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(searchbtn);